# How to return values from mongoose findOne method to the calling function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation where i am badly stuck. Tried a lot but no worth.
I have a nodejs application, where i am reading data from mongodb.
I have a main method, from where I am calling a `fetchMongo()` method and all other functions. I need the `fetchMongo` function to return the result to the Main. The main method has an object `obj` that will get passed to all the functions.
The code below I tried:  Its not working.
`console.log` inside `fetchMongo()` works fine, but `fetchMongo()` is not returning the value to Main.
Please help.

```
function fetchMongo(obj)
{
    var defer = Q.defer();
    serviceHealthConfig.findOne({}, '', { sort: {'_id' : -1} }, function(err, nodes){
        var struct={}
        if(err) 
            console.log(err);
        //console.log(nodes);
        obj = nodes;
        return obj;
    });
    defer.resolve(obj);
    return defer.promise;
}

function main(){
    var obj = { };
    var nodesObject = fetchMongo(obj)
                    .then(methOne(obj))
                    .then(methTwo(obj))
                    .then(methThree(obj))
}
```

Comment: You need to put `defer.resolve(obj);` inside `serviceHealthConfig`. When you reach `defer.resolve()`, `serviceHealthConfig` probably is still looking for the record on Mongo.

Comment: Moreover I think findOne require a parameter..what to find....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your defer.resolve should be called inside the find one callback. Like below:

```
    function fetchMongo(obj)
{
    var defer = Q.defer();
    serviceHealthConfig.findOne({}, '', { sort: {'_id' : -1} }, function(err, nodes){
        var struct={}
        if(err) 
            console.log(err);
        //console.log(nodes);
        obj = nodes;
        defer.resolve(obj);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Moreover findOne needs a parameter as well; what to find.

Hope this helps!